# C# how to get a property of an array of objects and make operations on him?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have an array of the object Card:
Card [] hand;
the object card has the property :
int CardValue
I need to get the maximal CardValue that is in the Card [] hand.

With my lacking knowledge, what I think I can do is to create a new int [] with all the card values of each card, but is there an eaiser way?

Comment: What have you tried to do for this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, LINQ has a [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) method for exactly this purpose:

```
int maxValue = hand.Max(card => card.CardValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the LINQ `Max` extension method:

```
var result = hand.Max(c => c.CardValue);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__